# return a value from a function making inputbox in powershell but this value seems empty

Tags: function, powershell

My function creates an inputbox.

```
function name-label {
    # Incorporate Visual Basic into script
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

    # show the Pop Up with the following text.
    $label = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Pas plus de 11 caractères`r`n`
    1) Que des lettres ou des chifres`
    2) Pas de caractères bizarres comme $ * µ %", "Nom de la clef USB", "")

    if ($label -eq "") {
        # OK or Cancel button pushed with no input
        Write-Host "Vous venez d'appuyer sur OK ou ANNULER avec un nom de volume vide" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black

        # Open new popup with the folloing text
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
        $answer = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Voulez-vous vraiment annuler ?", "Annuler ?", 4, "question")

        if ($answer -eq "YES") {
            # Yes button selected for cancel
            Write-Host "Projet annuler par l'utilisateur" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
            exit     # Quit the program
        } else {
            # You selected no, open a new pop up window withe the following text
            $a = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
            $intAnswer = $a.Popup("Vous n'avez pas entrer un nom pour la clé USB`r `n Nouvel essai !",0,"ERROR!",0)
            name-label # Restart function
        }
    }

    $label
}
name-label
Write-Host '---======---' $label   # This is what is returned from the function
```

Variable `$label` seems to be empty in `Write-Host`. I don't understand why and where is my issue.

So how to return correct value?

Comment: `Write-Host '---======---' $label` -> `Write-Host "---======--- $(name-label)"`. `$label` inside the function is a different variable in a different scope than the variable `$label` in the global scope.

Comment: ok it's better now but it seems that $(name-label) call a second time the function ?

Comment: `$label = name-label` at the second last line, read variable scope chapter of powershell help document.

Comment: It would now that you're actually calling the function in your code. Do `$label = name-label` to assign the function output to the variable you're using in the `Write-Host` statement.

Comment: Now it works like i want. I didn't know you could call a function like this